# Blender won't see my nVidia GPU and 2.90 crashes but 2.91 doesn't

Tags: gpu, osx

having a bit of a problem with Blender 2.90 and 2.91

My scene works in 2.83, and blender sees my GPU, no problems.  With 2.90 it can't see my GPU and it crashes on the same scene.  2.91 doesn't crash but it can't see my GPU.  Both 2.90 and 2.91 say "No Compatible GPUs found for path tracing. Cycles will render on the CPU".

My hardware is, Mac Pro (mid 2010), 24GB Ram, High Sierra,
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 TI.  Compute level 5.2 when I checked.
CUDA Driver Version 418.163, GPU Driver Version 387.10.10.10.40.138

2.83 is working great, yes its not blazing fast but fine for what I do.  I have not updated my OS for this machine because I want to use Blender and after High Sierra there is no support for NVIDIA on mac os :-(  It is what it is I guess. Whats up with 2.90 and 2.91 not seeing my GPU >

I can provide a crash report if it would help.

Comment: Did you solve this, noticing the same thing on 2.92 with a 980Ti